# MixPanel Issue Message not post

Tags: android, mixpanel

Cannot post message to https://api.mixpanel.com/track?ip=1. (Thread 37221)

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
```

Using Code:

```
  String projectToken = getString(R.string.mixpanel_key);
    MixpanelAPI mixpanel = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(this, projectToken);

    try {
        JSONObject props = new JSONObject();
        props.put("Gender", "Female");
        props.put("Logged in", false);
        mixpanel.track("MainActivity - onCreate yes", props);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to add properties to JSONObject", e);
    }
```

Please provide me any solution why this problem occurring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MixPanel Issue Message due to back end i think please use google analytics because its free of cost and also provide same functionality.likes tracking and click count  etc..